# Random Walk Steps Based on n Dice Rolls

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, coordinates, dice

I'm writing a function that takes 3 inputs P, Q, N and returns the location of a walker that steps based on the rolls of N dice according to following:

- If the outcome of the die is 1, the walker takes P steps toward east.
- If the outcome of the die is 2, the walker takes Q steps toward south.
- If the outcome of the die is 3, the walker takes Q+P steps toward north.
- If the outcome of the die is 4, the walker takes Q steps toward west.
- If the outcome of the die is 5, the walker takes P steps toward north and Q steps toward east.
- If the outcome of the die is 6, the walker takes Q steps toward south and P steps toward west.

And the function returns the final location of the walker with a list of two strings: for example ['3E', '4S'] shows at the end the walker has taken 3 steps toward the east and 4 steps toward south.

```py
import numpy.random

def walk_dice(P, Q, N):
    ans = list(numpy.random.randint(1,7,N))
    if 1 in ans:
        pos[0]+P
    elif 2 in ans:
        pos[1]-Q
    elif 3 in ans:
        pos[1]+P+Q
    elif 4 in ans:
        pos[0]-Q
    elif 5 in ans:
        pos[0]+Q
        pos[1]+P
    elif 6 in ans:
        pos[0]-P
        pos[1]-Q
    return pos

numpy.random.seed(seed=10)
print(walk_dice(3, 4, 2))
#[1, 2]
```

I get the same output everytime. Where am I going wrong with this code?

Comment: Where is `pos` defined?

Comment: Using python's built-in `random.randint` function is probably cleaner for selecting ans.

Comment: Code like `pos[0]+P` calculates the sum of `pos[0]` + `P`, but it doesn't store the result anywhere. you probably want sometime like `pos[0] = pos[0] + P` or just `pos[0] += P`.

Comment: You also never use N, so you only ever take 1 step.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
numpy.random.seed(seed=10)
```

(On a side note, most people do less typing by having `import numpy as np`).

But because you're setting the seed as the exact same thing each time, the outcome will always be exactly the same.

This should be fixed by just removing that line I pointed out.